# JBPM6.2 Form designer in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm

I am new to JBPm 6.2 and  successfully installed it on the windows machine. I am using the JBPM 6.2 using the eclipse plugin and created the sample workflow of JBPm using the eclipse.On the right click of the sampleworkflow.bpmn file I can see the option of Generta JBPM Forms.
But I can not see the form editor to edit the forms generated using the option?

Is it possible to edit the form generated using eclipse or is it possible only using the JBPM Console?If it is possbile to edit the JBPM generated form using eclipse please do let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kind of forms supported in jBPM 6.2:

- graphical forms: In the jBPM console you can generate / edit forms in a graphical environment (drag and drop etc.). These can only be edited in the console (they are stored as xml in a .form file and not meant to be edited outside)
- freemarker forms: These are HTML templates, targeted towards developers, that can be used to define forms with static and dynamic content.  These can be edited in Eclipse as well, using a simple text / XML editor, as they are simple HTML